# Copy 3 rows and paste them above

Tags: vba, copy, rows

I'm trying to find a value ~P~ in column A. Copy the row it is on, and the 2 next ones. And paste all 3 above the row i found ~P~ on.

I have this:

```
Private Sub NPaddlinebutton_Click() 
    Dim i As Long 
    For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1 
        If Range("A" & i).Value = "~P~" Then 
            Rows(i).Copy 
            Rows(i).Insert 
            Range("A" & i).ClearContents 
            Rows(i).Activate 
        End If 
    Next 
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 
End Sub
```

It works for 1 row, but can't figure out how to do it for 3 rows.
Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i did clearly understand what you are looking for, the code below should do. The key is to use a range to include what you want to "play" with. 3 rows for example. 
Let me know.

```
Private Sub NPaddlinebutton_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng3rows As Range
    Dim rng3CellsColumn As Range
    For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Range("A" & i).Value = "~P~" Then
            Set rng3rows = Range(Rows(i), Rows(i + 2))' using a range to include the 3 rows you want to copy over
            rng3rows.Copy
            Rows(i).Insert
            Set rng3CellsColumn = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + 2, 1))' using a range to clear the the cells in the column A
            rng3CellsColumn.ClearContents
            Rows(i).Activate 'here i suggest Rows(i).select. I think that's what you want
        End If
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set rng3rows = Nothing
    Set rng3CellsColumn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: yes i wanted to Select that row, but when i call it later with ActiveRow i get a error in debug saying ActiveRow = Empty

Comment: try activecell.Row instead e.g.: cells(activecell.Row, 2).value = Pclient.Value, as per your code

Comment: It worked, i owe you a beer...

Any tip on how i can easily switch between rows when inputing data from the userform? something like Cells(ActiveCell.Row+1, 2).Value = .............

Comment: Coming back to this... how do i change it to insert the rows below the 3 selected rows instead of above?

Comment: i cannot test it, but it should work if you do Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlUp

Comment: It still copies them above... i tried rows (i+3) but copies on itself then clears itself then ruins everything :d

Comment: maybe try:Rows(i - 3).Insert. but then, make sure that i-3 is always > 0 when trying to insert from above. In you loop set this condition: "If i - 3 > 0 Then". if true then the code can proceed

Comment: it loops copy-ing above and fills the worksheet up until row 1 :D

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Paddline_Click()
Dim i As Long
    Dim rng3rows As Range
    Dim rng3CellsColumn As Range
    For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Range("A" & i).Value = "~P~" Then
            Set rng3rows = Range(Rows(i), Rows(i + 2))  'using a range to include the 3 rows you want to copy over
            rng3rows.Copy
            Rows(i).Insert
            Set rng3CellsColumn = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + 2, 1))  'using a range to clear the the cells in the column A
            rng3CellsColumn.ClearContents
            Rows(i).Select
        End If
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set rng3rows = Nothing
    Set rng3CellsColumn = Nothing    
    'in randul 1
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value = Pclient.Value
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value = Pcodclient.Value
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 4).Value = ""
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5).Value = Pnrcomanda.Value
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 7).Value = Pdesc1.Value
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 8).Value = Pperscontact.Value
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 28).Value = Pstatus.Value    
    'in randul 2
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 2).Value = Pclient.Value
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 4).Value = ""
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 8).Value = Pdesc2.Value
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 10).Value = Pdurata.Value
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 11).Value = Pdatadelay.Value
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 27).Value = Pusername.Value
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 28).Value = Pstatus.Value    
    'in randul 3
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 2, 2).Value = Pclient.Value
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 2, 4).Value = ""
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 2, 8).Value = Pdesc3.Value
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 2, 10).Value = Pdurata.Value
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 2, 27).Value = PusernameV.Value    
MsgBox "Datele au fost introduse in tabel."
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 56
    Unload Me
```

Comment: you welcome, man. i am happy you found a solution to the other parts of your code!